# Can server hits the client directly

Tags: php

I have a small requirement in PHP as below. Some thing like chat.

For eg there are 2 users A & B.

When "A" clicks on "Chat" link.  "B" should automatically gets one javascript popup.

Is there any way of doing this except following.
- One JS script runs continuously with AJAX. 
I dont want to happen client-server interaction continuously.

Is there any way for server sending status to browser directly?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it the other way, instead of Ajax use [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)). That way the server pushes data to the client without the client expecting it. The Facebook chat uses this technique.

Answer (score 0):

Are you worried about wasting bandwidth? Why not [try out XMPP](http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.shtml)? There are php libraries as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use polling (the JavaScript client keeps checking with the server every once in a while using AJAX) or use something like a Java Applet which would establish a separate connection with server and keep it on for communicating back and forth. If you use a Java Applet, then you should probably use server side Java as that would be the most effective.

Comment: Comet can either be implemented using AJAX + polling or using Java Applets. It is not a separate technology.